# A vertical Array view, probably NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

Im seeking a tutorial/solution using a `NSView` where the array is displayed vertically.

This `NSView` is then placed in the `NSScrollView` for vertical scrolling up/down.

Its a bit like a 'NSTableView' but with 1 column. That one column contains many rows (as many in the array) of custom NSViews.

The custom NSView contains editable NSTextfields, NSImage and so forth for the various NSDictionary elements in each array object.

Possibly, its a subclass to NSOutlineView. But most tutorials Ive seen so far only show textfield and/or image. Further, I do not need the left pane of NSOutlineView.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont need collapsing it would be NSTableView with 1 view per array element. for a complex array element, you would have a complex NSTableViewCellView.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bzEA0FuivY maybe ;)

Comment: looks promising. and there are some examples should one look up that keyword "complex NSTableViewCellView"